# Granger Causality with or without VAR

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I would like to test two stationary time series (say a and b) for Granger Causality. I am familiar with the method of running two regressions:

```
a=const+a[-1]+e_1
a=const+a[-1]+b[-1]+e_1
```

And then using an F Test (I omitted the degrees of freedom): `(R2f-R2r)/(1-R2r)` 
Afterwards I do the same the other way around:

```
b=const+b[-1]e_2
b=const+b[-1]+a[-1]+e_2
```

This would then tell me which of them Granger causes the other one.

How is a VAR different from this (or is the set up above basically already a VAR)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the perspective of testing for Granger causality, your setup is exactly the same as a VAR(1) setup *if equation-by-equation OLS is used for estimating the restricted VAR*.

1. The coefficient estimates and their standard errors in your individual equations will be obtained in exactly the same way as in the VAR(1) model and will have the same values, both in the restricted case and the unrestricted case.
2. The test will be carried out in the same way: the $F$-statistic will be calculated from the same elements and it will be compared to the same critical values.

Thus I see no difference between your approach and a VAR(1) when it comes to testing for Granger causality.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, thank you so much Richard!!

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia, You are welcome!

Comment: It's more like you're saying that from a Granger causality test setup one can build a VAR. But for the F-test you need the error sum of squares from the restricted model, which you don't get from a standard reduced VAR estimation.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, thanks for the comment! What I am saying is the other way around: if you have a VAR(1) and the OPs equations and want to test for GC, then there is no difference which one you use. You are right that you do not get sum of squares of the restricted model from standard VAR estimation; that is why I wrote explicitly in my point 1. that there is the restricted *and* the unrestricted case. I also wrote in my first paragraph that there is a restricted VAR model being estimated. Does that explain it?

Comment: @RichardHardy with all these considerations, yes. Still, seems like we had this possible "equivalence" of the procedures thought in different ways, that is way, to me, answering OP's question with no further assumptions leads to a negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

The VAR is a model, and OLS is a technique to estimate a model, but in essence, yes, that is it - one typically estimates VAR models with OLS regressions for each equation and assesses the significance of each of the coefficients on the lags of the variables of the variable whose Granger causality is to be investigated.

This happens more commonly with a $\chi^2$-test that is asymptotically valid even without normal errors, unlike the F-test, but that distinction is often not practically important.

Answer (score 0):

A [vector autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) (VAR) intends to model existing linear relationships in set of time series. On the other hand, [Granger-causality](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Granger_causality) is a concept (related to the relevance of other variables in forecasting another one), that can be tested, for two variables (for example, since it can be multivariate), using the linear models you cited.

Specifically, the set up in a Granger-causality test you presented do not correspond to a VAR, since the latter must contain - in its reduced form - lags of both variables in a symmetric fashion. For example, a VAR(1) on your variables $a$ and $b$, would look like:

$$
a_t=c_a+\beta_1^a a_{t-1}+\beta^a_2b_{t-1}+e^a_t\\
b_t=c_b+\beta_1^b b_{t-1}+\beta^b_2a_{t-1}+e^b_t
$$

The system above together with some [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression#Definition) regarding the error terms completely defines a VAR(1) model. Now compare this with the set up you presented and the difference should be better illustrated.

Comment: Granger causality can be tested for two or more variables and between two or more groups of variables, not just two variables.

Comment: @RichardHardy That's why I left it explicit in my first paragraph I was addressing the bivariate case, actually for making it easy to compare with a VAR(1). Still, the idea of the explanation doesn't change for more than two variable.

Comment: It just appeared to me that there is a flavour of contrast between your first and second sentences, and I found it misleading. Not to say you are wrong, but perhaps it can be phrased in a way such that the apparent contrast is avoided?

Comment: What is still confusing me a bit however is that fact Granger causaility appears to be examined within VARs. From our discussion so far, my understanding is that I could analyze Granger causality without a VAR using my approach above (for 2 or more variables). But I could also do this using a VAR, but I would not have to. So if I chose to use a VAR for other purposes, I could just test Granger causality along the way and I would get the same result as I would from my approach above, right?

Comment: Put differently, in this context a VAR is just one method of conducting a Granger causality test (which should yield the same result as my method above). Of course a VAR also serves a whole number of other purposes ...

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia to test for granger causality in a bivariate set up, for example, you'd need one equation of its VAR model. The other one, not present in the VAR, excludes the other variable. It is in this sense I'm calling the two approaches different (namely, you can't test for Granger causality if you have only an estimated VAR). Nonetheless, as the answer by Christoph Hanck pointed out, it is usual - but not necessary - to use OLS in both cases.

Comment: I do not understand the first half of the comment. Furthermore, in which sense *you can't test for Granger causality if you have only an estimated VAR*? In my understanding, an estimated VAR plus a table of critical values is all you need for testing Granger causality. I also do not understand how you find a difference between the OPs approach and VAR: *the set up in a Granger-causality test you presented do not correspond to a VAR, since the latter must contain<...> lags of both variables in a symmetric fashion*. The OPs equations are just what you ask for: there are symmetric lags there.

Comment: @RichardHardy from OP's question, where exactly does the term "a=const+a[-1]+e_1" appears in a bivariate VAR(1) model?

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, it appears in the restricted VAR model that will, together with the unrestricted VAR model, be used for testing for Granger causality.

Comment: @RichardHardy but then we're talking of two VAR estimations, my interpretation of OP's questions considers he's only talking about the usual, unrestricted case.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, fine, I do not argue that there are no alternative ways of looking at it. I just pointed out how the OPs approach is equivalent to a VAR approach. I do not say you cannot come up with another twist to VAR such that it is not equivalent. And there is nothing wrong with it, of course.

Comment: @RichardHardy well, I'd hardly call not assuming an auxiliary estimation a 'twist' of a model, but I get your point.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, sorry, perhaps I chose a charged word. I am not a native speaker. I do appreciate your input and I do not aim to argue, just to explain the things I am trying to tell. Thanks! :)

Comment: @RichardHardy oh, neither me. That's why I said I agreed to your observation. I also apologize for sounding rough then.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, No offense taken! :)